# jQuery : select element with no text but also containing an element with text

Tags: jquery, html

I want to remove entire DIVs containing no text but only if it does not contain a child element with text.

I've tried things like:

```js
$("div").each(function() {
  var expurge = $(this).find('label').remove().end().text();
  if (expurge === null) {
    this.remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><label>A</label></div>
<div><label>B</label>some text</div>
<div><label>C</label></div>
```

But it removes all the div not just the empty ones. What am I missing ?

Comment: what an unclear question ! . please improve

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
$("div").each(function() {
  var expurge = $(this).clone().children().remove().end().text();
  if (!expurge.trim()) {
    $(this).remove();
  }
});
```

It will check if the string(of the div) is null or empty

It will return: Bsome text

**demo**

```js
$("div").each(function() {
  var expurge = $(this).clone().children().remove().end().text();
  if (!expurge.trim()) {
    $(this).remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><label>A</label></div>
<div><label>B</label>some text</div>
<div><label>C</label></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need much jquery method chaining here, just check if the element contains any text node or not, essentially `this.nodeType == 3`

```js
$("div").each(function() {
  var textNodes = $(this).contents().filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType == 3;
  }).length;
  
  if(textNodes===0)
    $(this).remove();
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><label>A</label></div>
<div><label>B</label>some text</div>
<div><label>C</label></div>
```